# How to convert arbitory hex to ascii in c?

Tags: c, ascii, hex

How to convert `00000000004004d8` to ascii string?

E.g., `41` is for `A`?

Comment: How is `42` interpreted as `A`? ??? *In ASCII, the character `A` has a value of 65 (decimal; 0x41 hexadecimal)* Also you need to figure out how to deal with hexadecimal values outside range and with odd-length input strings.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) to do that. Something like:

```
char c[8];
sscanf("00000000004004d8", "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", 
   &c[0],
   &c[1],
   &c[2],
   &c[3],
   &c[4],
   &c[5],
   &c[6],
   &c[7]);
```

Comment: How to make `00000000004004d8` a parameter,so that it can work for arbitory hex?